# How can I change threshold value in the evaluation of deep model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, evaluate

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile``
CSV_COLUMNS = [   ]


train_file = '/home/nick/
test_file = '/home/nick/

def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle):
  #"""Input builder function."""
  df_data = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open(data_file),
      names=CSV_COLUMNS,
      skipinitialspace=True,
      engine="python",
      skiprows=1)
  # remove NaN elements
  df_data = df_data.dropna(how="any", axis=0) 

  labels = df_data["NPK"].apply(lambda x: "<10" in x).astype(int)

  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
      x=df_data,
      y=labels,
      batch_size=100,
      num_epochs=num_epochs,
      shuffle=shuffle,
      num_threads=5)

DA = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(  )
LO = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(    )


deep_columns = [tf.feature_column.indicator_column(DA)  tf.feature_column.indicator_column(PD)

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=deep_columns,
    hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256],
    optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
      learning_rate=0.1,
      l1_regularization_strength=0.001
    ))
# set num_epochs to None to get infinite stream of data.
m.fit(
    input_fn=input_fn(train_file, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True),
    steps=20000)

# set steps to None to run evaluation until all data consumed.
results = m.evaluate(
    input_fn=input_fn(test_file, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False),
    steps=None)
print("model directory = %s" % model_dir)
#in the result we have accuracy, precision auc and other things.       How can I choose them?
for key in sorted(results):
  print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

I'd like to know how I can change threshold value in the evaluation of the deep model. This is the code, if you run it you can see that this value is 0.5, I'd like to change it from o to 1 to improve the model 
I hope you can help me 
thank you